# Can't connect to SQL Server 2005 x64 SP 4 on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

I have an issue with connecting to SQL Server 2005 x64 SP 4 on Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio 2008 DataBase edition.
I always receives message about error 26 and named pipes provider. It is irrational because I have disabled firewall, enabled named pipes protocol, enabled sql server browser, enabled remote connections etc.
Do anybody have an idea why it is happening? :( Please help.

Comment: Is this the 2008 R2 GDR version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the resolution. Visual Studio Database edition keeps connection string to sql server it two places. (two different text boxes - sic!)

Those places are:

1.Options->Database Tools->Data Connections

2.Options->Database Tools->Design-Time Validation Database

If you have named instance you have to put there only the name of a instance without host name.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already found the article: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_protocols/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serverinstance-specified)

In addition to what is covered in the article, I would be curious to know if you can connect to a different instance or using a different protocol (TCP/IP).

Any clues in the event log?

Is this a named instance?